# Identify all events occurred in a single transaction

Tags: solidity, web3.py

Is it possible to identify all the events occurred within a single transaction?
I just want to group events by transaction, but looks like it is not possible. e.g. all the events have different transaction_hash, log_index etc.
I'm using the python bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list all the event logs from a transaction by [getting its receipt](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html#web3.eth.Eth.getTransactionReceipt). For example, see the two events in the `logs` attribute of this receipt:

```
In [1]: from web3.auto import w3

In [2]: w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(0xf12438191fe6b9d8b6a8538db019b55530eaf2c8adfd60efed5582d0b9b105f8)
Out[2]: 
AttributeDict({'blockHash': HexBytes('0x7b3f60d80b0decdd81f6c440244339dfdf55c28c333d40e228f611249941c99e'),
 'blockNumber': 5810115,
 'contractAddress': None,
 'cumulativeGasUsed': 1790581,
 'gasUsed': 457319,
 'logs': [AttributeDict({'address': '0x6090A6e47849629b7245Dfa1Ca21D94cd15878Ef',
   'blockHash': HexBytes('0x7b3f60d80b0decdd81f6c440244339dfdf55c28c333d40e228f611249941c99e'),
   'blockNumber': 5810115,
   'data': '0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005b2e1471',
   'logIndex': 4,
   'topics': [HexBytes('0x87e97e825a1d1fa0c54e1d36c7506c1dea8b1efd451fe68b000cf96f7cf40003'),
    HexBytes('0x1420e66a1e668e86523b1a38a679ff5881780882d2643a4636650c4cc6df7491')],
   'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xf12438191fe6b9d8b6a8538db019b55530eaf2c8adfd60efed5582d0b9b105f8'),
   'transactionIndex': 60,
   'transactionLogIndex': '0x0',
   'type': 'mined'}),
  AttributeDict({'address': '0x6090A6e47849629b7245Dfa1Ca21D94cd15878Ef',
   'blockHash': HexBytes('0x7b3f60d80b0decdd81f6c440244339dfdf55c28c333d40e228f611249941c99e'),
   'blockNumber': 5810115,
   'data': '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003782dace9d900000',
   'logIndex': 5,
   'topics': [HexBytes('0xb556ff269c1b6714f432c36431e2041d28436a73b6c3f19c021827bbdc6bfc29'),
    HexBytes('0xa5561362dcede2db42f5e9c2be06fd01930a452a43b740e0970325bc4c993794'),
    HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000057b76fe5ed71dd788532df2ae2ea37bf67c4ade4')],
   'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xf12438191fe6b9d8b6a8538db019b55530eaf2c8adfd60efed5582d0b9b105f8'),
   'transactionIndex': 60,
   'transactionLogIndex': '0x1',
   'type': 'mined'})],
 'logsBloom': HexBytes('0x00000000000000008000000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000200000000001000100000000040000000000000000000004000000000000000800000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000001000000000000'),
 'root': None,
 'status': 1,
 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xf12438191fe6b9d8b6a8538db019b55530eaf2c8adfd60efed5582d0b9b105f8'),
 'transactionIndex': 60})
```